# Where should I put a validation method that would be considered best practice?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So I have a validation method to check for a correct zip code for use in my API (REST Framework on Django). I've currently placed this above all my class/one off views (endpoints for my API) in views.py (of my app) but I feel like this is not the correct OOP way to do it?

Here is my validation method:

```
def zipValidate(s):
    s = s.replace(' ', '')

    if len(s) == 5 and s[0:5].isdigit():
        return s
    else:
        return False
```

Used later down in my view:

```
# Custom API View for Zip Code check
@api_view(['GET'])
def zip_code(request, zc):
    # Check zip code for errors
    zc_clean = zipValidate(zc)

    if zc_clean == False:
        return Response({'error': 'Zip code given is invalid.'})
```

Is it OK to leave this in the views.py? Or should I make another .py (maybe validators.py) and import it into the view? What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: If you are using forms.py then add all the server side validations inside your form class itself.

Comment: I'm not using any forms. This is a jSON API call that will get a jSON request. No forms, no website, just jSON calls back & forth.

Comment: It depends. Are you going to use that code somewhere else? If no then leave it. If yes then move it to a separate file. :)

Answer (score 1):

Django keeps its built-in validators in the [`django.core.validators`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#built-in-validators) module.

If you followed this you could create a `validators.py` in your app.

You'd then `import validators` and use `validators.zipValidate(s)` or `from validators import zipValidate` and use `zipValidate(s)` as you are.

I hope that helps.